# select decimal value through LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get decimal value using LINQ in a MVC3 project.

How do I get it? it looks easy question, but I cannot get single decimal value not list which is Product.aWeekPrice.

How can I get the particular threeDayPrice? After getting threeDayPrice, it will be used in if condition for giving different conditions as you can see in my code below:

```
    public decimal GetTotal(decimal price)
    {
        // Multiply product price by count of that album to get 
        // the current price for each of those product in the cart
        // sum all product price totals to get the cart total

        //In select part, I have got error, 'cannot convert type 
        //'System.Linq.IQueryable<decimal>' to 'decimal'

        decimal threeDayPrice = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                              where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                                 select (decimal)cartItems.Product.threeDayPrice);

        decimal aWeekPrice = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                                 where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                                 select (decimal)cartItems.Product.aWeekPrice);

        if (price == threeDayPrice)
        {
            decimal? total = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                              where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                              select (int?)cartItems.count * cartItems.Product.threeDayPrice).Sum();
            return total ?? decimal.Zero;
        }

        else if (price == aWeekPrice)
        {
            decimal? total = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                              where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                              select (int?)cartItems.count * cartItems.Product.aWeekPrice).Sum();
            return total ?? decimal.Zero;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: What is the data type of threeDayPrice/aWeekPrice?  Are they a collections of decimals, or just decimals?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MVC.  It's a database question so it's either Entity Framework or Linq to Sql, not sure which

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your query **always** returns  only one value use [`.Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx) to get it as `decimal` instead of a collection of decimals.

```
    decimal threeDayPrice = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                          where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                             select (decimal)cartItems.Product.threeDayPrice).Single();

    decimal aWeekPrice = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                             where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                             select (decimal)cartItems.Product.aWeekPrice).Single();
```

If there is a possibility that the query will return more then one or zero elements use [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx)/[`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but when I put .Single() or First(), or FirstOr Default(), it happens error on public decimal GetTotal(decimal price). it is saying 'not all code paths return a value'. what does it mean?

Comment: This is not a LINQ error. In your method no value is returned when (`price != threeDayPrice and price != aWeekPrice`) (no if-statement it executed then). You should add `return decimal.Zero;` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 3):

That error message indicates that cartItems.Product.aWeekPrice is a collection, not a single.  So, you just need to select whichever item you need.  For example:

```
decimal threeDayPrice = (from cartItems in db.Cart
                     where cartItems.cartId == ShoppingCartId
                     select (decimal)cartItems.Product.threeDayPrice).FirstOrDefault();
```

should remove the error message, but it will do so by selecting the first item in the "threeDayPrice" field.